# C# executable (get rdtsc timestamp) crashes intermittently

Tags: c#, .net, timestamp, rdtsc

I have copied this code that queries rdtsc timestamp in C#.

The equivalent in C++ is just `__rdtsc()`

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
public static class Rdtsc
{
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate ulong FuncUInt64();
    private const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04;
    private const uint PAGE_EXECUTE = 0x10;
    private const uint PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;
    private const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;
    private const uint MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000;
    public static readonly FuncUInt64 Timestamp;
    public static readonly FuncUInt64 TimestampP;
    public static readonly bool IsRdtscSupported;
    public static readonly bool IsRdtscPSupported;
    static Rdtsc()
    {
        SystemInfo systemInfo;
        GetNativeSystemInfo(out systemInfo);
        if (systemInfo.wProcessorArchitecture != 0 && systemInfo.wProcessorArchitecture != 9)
        {
            Timestamp = StopwatchGetTimestamp;
            TimestampP = StopwatchGetTimestamp;
            IsRdtscSupported = false;
            IsRdtscPSupported = false;
            return;
        }
        byte[] cpuid;
        byte[] rdtsc;
        byte[] rdtscp;
        byte[] rdtsccpuid;
        IsRdtscSupported = true;
        if (Is64Bit())
        {
            cpuid = new byte[]
            {
                0x53, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x0F, 0xA2, 0xBB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x39, 0xD8, 0x72, 0x16, 0x89, 0xD8,
                0x48, 0xC7, 0xC2, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0F, 0xA2, 0x89, 0xC8, 0x48, 0xC1, 0xE0, 0x20, 0x48, 0x09, 0xD0, 0xEB,
                0x03, 0x48, 0x31, 0xC0, 0x5B, 0xC3
            };
            rdtsc = new byte[] { 0x0F, 0x31, 0x48, 0xC1, 0xE2, 0x20, 0x48, 0x09, 0xD0, 0xC3 };
            rdtscp = new byte[] { 0x0F, 0x01, 0xF9, 0x48, 0xC1, 0xE2, 0x20, 0x48, 0x09, 0xD0, 0xC3 };
            rdtsccpuid = new byte[]
                {0x53, 0x31, 0xC0, 0x0F, 0xA2, 0x0F, 0x31, 0x48, 0xC1, 0xE2, 0x20, 0x48, 0x09, 0xD0, 0x5B, 0xC3};
        }
        else
        {
            cpuid = new byte[]
            {
                0x53, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x0F, 0xA2, 0xBB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x39, 0xD8, 0x72, 0x0A, 0x89, 0xD8,
                0x0F, 0xA2, 0x89, 0xD0, 0x89, 0xCA, 0xEB, 0x04, 0x31, 0xC0, 0x31, 0xD2, 0x5B, 0xC3
            };
            rdtsc = new byte[] { 0x0F, 0x31, 0xC3 };
            rdtscp = new byte[] { 0x0F, 0x01, 0xF9, 0xC3 };
            rdtsccpuid = new byte[] { 0x53, 0x31, 0xC0, 0x0F, 0xA2, 0x0F, 0x31, 0x5B, 0xC3 };
        }
        var buf = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            var cpuidLength = (cpuid.Length & 63) != 0 ? (cpuid.Length | 63) + 1 : cpuid.Length;
            var rdtscLength = (rdtsc.Length & 63) != 0 ? (rdtsc.Length | 63) + 1 : rdtsc.Length;
            var rdtscpLength = (rdtscp.Length & 63) != 0 ? (rdtscp.Length | 63) + 1 : rdtscp.Length;
            var rdtsccpuidLength = (rdtsccpuid.Length & 63) != 0 ? (rdtsccpuid.Length | 63) + 1 : rdtsccpuid.Length;
            var totalLength = cpuidLength + rdtscLength + Math.Max(rdtscpLength, rdtsccpuidLength);
            buf = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)totalLength, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
            if (buf != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(cpuid, 0, buf, cpuid.Length);
                for (var i = cpuid.Length; i < cpuidLength; i++)
                    Marshal.WriteByte(buf, i, 0x90);
                Marshal.Copy(rdtsc, 0, buf + cpuidLength, rdtsc.Length);
                for (var i = rdtsc.Length; i < rdtscLength; i++)
                    Marshal.WriteByte(buf, cpuidLength + i, 0x90);
                var cpuidFunc = (FuncUInt64)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(buf, typeof(FuncUInt64));
                var supportedFeatures = cpuidFunc();
                byte[] rdtscpSelected;
                int rdtscpSelectedLength;
                if ((supportedFeatures & (1L << 27)) != 0)
                {
                    rdtscpSelected = rdtscp;
                    rdtscpSelectedLength = rdtscpLength;
                    IsRdtscPSupported = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rdtscpSelected = rdtsccpuid;
                    rdtscpSelectedLength = rdtsccpuidLength;
                    IsRdtscPSupported = false;
                }
                Marshal.Copy(rdtscpSelected, 0, buf + cpuidLength + rdtscLength, rdtscpSelected.Length);
                for (var i = rdtscpSelected.Length; i < rdtscpSelectedLength; i++)
                    Marshal.WriteByte(buf, cpuidLength + rdtscLength + i, 0x90);
                var result = VirtualProtect(buf, (IntPtr)totalLength, PAGE_EXECUTE, out var oldProtection);
                if (result)
                {
                    Timestamp = (FuncUInt64)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(buf + cpuidLength, typeof(FuncUInt64));
                    TimestampP = (FuncUInt64)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(buf + cpuidLength + rdtscLength,
                        typeof(FuncUInt64));
                    buf = IntPtr.Zero;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (buf != IntPtr.Zero)
                VirtualFree(buf, IntPtr.Zero, MEM_RELEASE);
        }
    }
    private static bool Is64Bit()
    {
        return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8;
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(out SystemInfo lpSystemInfo);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool VirtualProtect(IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, out uint lpflOldProtect);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool VirtualFree(IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint dwFreeType);
    private static ulong StopwatchGetTimestamp()
    {
        return unchecked((ulong)Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SystemInfo
    {
        public readonly ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
        public readonly ushort wReserved;
        public readonly uint dwPageSize;
        public readonly IntPtr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
        public readonly IntPtr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
        public readonly IntPtr dwActiveProcessorMask;
        public readonly uint dwNumberOfProcessors;
        public readonly uint dwProcessorType;
        public readonly uint dwAllocationGranularity;
        public readonly ushort wProcessorLevel;
        public readonly ushort wProcessorRevision;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Timestamp());
    }
}
```

Now one of 2 things happen when I run this.

```
1.    1754797499369025

    ...\Proj.exe (process 43924) exited with code 0.
    Press any key to close this window . . .


2. The application to execute does not exist: 'Proj.dll'.

   ...\Proj.exe (process 53340) exited with code -2147450726.
    Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Sone for 1. program executes and outputs expected value, for 2 it crashes with this error.
So I have 2 questions.

1. Is there a more straightforward and less painful way to get rdtcs timestamp?
2. Does anyone have a clue what the can be done to fix the code above?

Comment: Looks like it's been [asked for for a while](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6956) as a Hardware Intrinsic but the comments suggest it's unlikely to be surfaced (although how much weight to grant those comments I'll leave to you)

Comment: [Documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps#direct-tsc-usage) "We strongly discourage using the RDTSC or RDTSCP processor instruction to directly query the TSC because you won't get reliable results on some versions of Windows, across live migrations of virtual machines, and on hardware systems without invariant or tightly synchronized TSCs. Instead, we encourage you to use QPC to leverage the abstraction, consistency, and portability that it offers."

Comment: So you should probably just using existing mechanisms such as `Stopwatch` or PInvoke `QueryPerformanceCounter`